# Login form in CodeIgniter calls the controller in URL each time wrong credentials are given

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, authentication

I'm creating a login form using CodeIgniter. The login function works perfectly when correct credentials are given. And when wrong credentials are given, it will display a custom message. Now the problem is that if I enter wrong credential once, the url changes to a certain one. Though this displays the same login form, I cannot login even with correct credentials thereafter.

The whole scenario is:

- On clicking a login link, it displays a login form and the url is http://mydomain.com/myproject/c_login
- If I enter wrong credentials, a message is shown using the argument sent inside the **index()**, and then the same login form is shown, but this time with the url http://mydomain.com/myproject/c_login/c_fun_login_process
- If I enter wrong credential again, it becomes http://mydomain.com/myproject/c_login/c_login/c_fun_login_process
- Meaning, every time I enter a wrong username and password combination, it calls the controller again and again that the url gets added with a **c_login** controller.

How can I solve this issue?

I have this controller code for login function

```
<?php
class C_login extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index($msg = NULL){
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->view('v_login', $data);
}
public function c_fun_login_process(){
    $this->load->model('m_login_model');
    $result = $this->m_login_model->m_fun_login_validate();

    if(! $result){
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index($msg);
    }else{

        redirect('c_view_page/c_fun_dashboard');
    }        
}
```

And this is the login form in the view file **(v_login)**

```
  <form method="post" action="<?php '.base_url().'?>c_login/c_fun_login_process" name="process">
             <?php
            if (!is_null($msg))
                echo $msg;
            ?>
```

This apparently is a minor issue which anyone with a pretty decent knowledge of CodeIgniter can solve. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be safe, build your form using the native helper:

```
<?php echo form_open('c_login/c_fun_login_process');?>
```

Or use any other url function (from the url helper, be sure to have it loaded beforehand):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('c_login/c_fun_login_process');?>" name="process">
```

This way you don't have to worry about building wrong urls and facing problems like that.

Comment: Awesome. I thought using it in the normal form wouldn't make much difference. Worked easily perfect. Thank you so much.